# How to determine the degree of these polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

I have two functions, $p_1,p_2\in\mathcal{H}(\mathbb{C})$ verifying $p_1(p_2(z))=z^2$. I have to prove that $p_1$ and $p_2$ are polynomials and, in addition, show that one of them has degree equal to 1 and the other equal to 2.

After reading [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2323124/g-circ-f-non-constant-polynomials-then-f-and-g-are-polynomials) I know how to solve the first part, but I have no idea how to prove the second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $p_1$ and $p_2$ are polynomials, then $\deg(p_1 \circ p_2) = \deg (p_1) \cdot \deg (p_2)$. But $\deg(p_1 \circ p_2) = \deg(z^2) = 2$, and this only factorises as $1 \cdot 2$ or $2\cdot 1$.